# Get the variable by its name

Tags: java

How can I access the variable value by providing the String that contains name of that variable?
Like this:

```
int var1 = 123;
getVariableByName("var1");
```

It should return 123
I know that I can create a HashMap or something...
But can I do this shortly, without a couple of code?

I need to create some objects with similar data, so I did this:
(I'm working with android)

```
String string2="bla";
String string2="bla-bla";
String string3="bla-bla-bla"

for(int i=1; i<=2; i++){
   TextView tv = new TextView;
   TextView.setText(getValueOf("string"+i));
}
```

Just it isn't smart to make a huge HashMap if you need to create a lot of objects. There should be a way to do it optimised...

Comment: Can you give us more context regarding why you think you need to do this?  ... perhaps some more code.

Comment: More context needed. Is that a field in a class -> reflection. Is that a local variable in a method -> not possible. In both cases you should not do it at all and stay type safe.

Comment: i guess he needs a method that it can take dynamic variable and then it retrieve the it's value

Comment: what do you want to do with the value after you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with local variables in Java. Local variables are variables you define inside a method. The names do not survive compilation step and are not available at runtime.

You can lookup fields via reflection via Foo.class.getField or obj.getClass().getField

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new in java, didn't think to use arrays. But you helped me a lot! :)